# Генерация строк из заданных символов и заданной начальной комбинацией

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, строки

Нужно сгенерировать строки заданной длины из заданного алфавита.
С обычным декартовым произведением проблем нет, `itertools.product()` прекрасно работает. Но вот как начать генерацию с заданной комбинации?

```
import itertools

symbols = 'abcdfghijk'
length = 5
start_string = 'dfgkj'  # Строка, с которой нужно начать

# Последовательная генерация всех вариантов
for line in itertools.product(symbols, repeat=length):
    print(*line, sep='')
```

UPD: длина алфавита и длина генерируемых строк может быть больше

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зная принцип обхода комбинаций, можно посчитать позицию для генератора. Дальше, применяя [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), смещаем генератор.

```
import itertools

def find_pos(symbols, fstr):
    return sum(len(symbols) ** (len(fstr) - p) * symbols.index(s) for p, s in enumerate(fstr, 1))

symbols = 'abcdfghijk'
length = 5
start_string = 'dfgkj'


line_0 = ''
gen = itertools.product(symbols, repeat=length)
for line in itertools.islice(gen, find_pos(symbols, start_string), len(symbols) ** length):
    # print(*line, sep='')
    if not line_0:
        line_0 = ''.join(line)

assert(start_string == line_0)
print(line_0, ''.join(line))  # -> dfgkj kkkkk
```

P.S. Вывод каждой строки закомментировал, т.к. большой объем. Для проверки запоминаю первую строку, вывожу вместе с последней.

Comment: Спасибо за решение и за новые знания. В коде разобрался, но хотелось бы получше понять, почему такая формула расчета позиции. Что почитать?

Comment: Насчет формулы - я ее подобрал опытным путем. А вообще, это вопросы основ комбинаторики, читать надо о них.

Answer (score 1):

можно так, но я уверен есть способ лучше

```
import itertools

symbols = 'abcdfghijk'
length = 5
start_string = 'dfgkj'  # Строка, с которой нужно начать

# Последовательная генерация всех вариантов
lst = list(itertools.product(symbols, repeat=length))
for line in lst[lst.index(tuple(start_string)):]:
    print(*line, sep='')
```

Comment: Спасибо. Для текущей задачи всё отлично работает. Но при увеличении алфавита и длины генерируемых строк получаем "MemoryError". Об этом не было сказано в условии, поэтому добавлю апдейт

Comment: Отличный пример, как делать НЕ стоит. Высчитывать и держать в памяти все значения Декартова произведения - наихудший вариант.